# DynamoDB DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE not working with DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to add creation timestamp using DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE to my items in dynamo db, my mapper is initialized with config: DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES, but when I check my item in Dynamo DB it doesn't get updated.

Similarly I also have DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS, which gets updated on creating an item, I also checked aws code for DynamoDBAutoGenerator, it mentions there is some limitations of using CREATE with DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS.: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGenerator.java

Creation and lastUpdated Timestamps:

```
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedTimestamp
    private Long creationTimestamp;

    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedTimestamp
    private Long lastUpdatedTimestamp;
```

Mapper Initialization:

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    public DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClientWithMapper(
            @Named("standardAwsCred") AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentials,
            @Named("dynamodb.realm") String region) {
        final DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder configBuilder = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder();
        configBuilder.setSaveBehavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES);
        DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig = configBuilder.build();
        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(awsCredentials)
                .withRegion(region)
                .build(), dynamoDBMapperConfig);
        return new DynamoDbClient(dynamoDBMapper);
    }
```

How can I get this to work? I have a solution that is to not have DynamoDBMapperConfig or keep it as default while creating Mapper and pass it everytime I have to update an item, but I don't prefer using this way can anyone suggest how can I make the above code work?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the DynamoDBGenerator it seems it won't be possible to get that behavior if we stick to the UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES

Other options are:

- A) Setting the creationTimestamp when we create the Object
- B) Using a SaveExpression to define the *creation* of creationTimestamp when *saving* a new object
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBSaveExpression.html

It seems to be one of the shortcommings of DynamoDBMapper to limit it to a subset of Save.Behaviors

Please feel free to request it as a feature in 
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/35